# Why safe call (?.) is needed on a layout binding variable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working with the codelab:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#3

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val myName: MyName = MyName("Aleks Haecky")
  ...
```

the MyName class:

```
data class MyName(var name: String = "", var nickname: String = "")
```

databinding variable in the layout:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="myName"
        type="com.example.aboutme.MyName" />
</data>
```

the code in main activity where an an event handler is set

```
...
    binding.doneButton.setOnClickListener {
        addNickname(it)
    }
}

private fun addNickname(view: View) {
    binding.apply {
        myName.nickname = nicknameEdit.text.toString()
...
```

why does the variable myName generate the following error?

**Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type MyName?**

myName is not declared nullable. So why myName?.nickname is needed?

Comment: You can read here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because the variable **myName** in

```
binding.apply {
   myName?.nickname = nicknameEdit.text.toString()
   invalidateAll()
   ...
}
```

is not refers to this

```
private val myName: MyName = MyName("Aleks Haecky")
```

but it refers to the **myName** in this xml

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="myName"
        type="com.example.aboutme.MyName" />
</data>
```

And all variables that you define on layout xml file are nullable. That's why you need a safe call (?.) every time you want to access it.

Comment: "And all variables that you define on layout xml file are nullable." Is this always true? Is there a documentation?

Comment: Yes, because you always need to declare it in oncreate like binding.myName = myName before you access it. if you dont do that, the value of variable myName on layout xml will null

Comment: binding.myName is refers to variable on layout xml and myName is the object of MyName class that you have defined

Comment: if you still confuse, you can try to make a different name for those variable so that you will be easier to understand it

Comment: I changed the myName to myName2 in MainActivity to make it clear.  binding.myName = myName2. The app ran smoothly. When I commented out the binding.myName = myName2 line, the app ran but displayed nothing where the name is to be displayed. The myName?. line helped remove compile time error, but the app became buggy! Am I mistaken?

Comment: it display nothing because you didn't assign any value for variable myName. thats why you must assign it in oncreate binding.myName = myName2